# How to add a subview to a UITableViewCell and resize it while in editing mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uislider

Edit: I'm starting a bounty on this one, as I'm looking for a "cleaner" solution with a `UITableViewCell` **subclass**, rather than messing with the `UITableView` delegate and datasource. Ideally, I'd like to see how could I also handle the `UISlider` events. Thanks!

I am using a group-styled `UITableView` and I have several cells that look like this:

[image]

Now, while I'm **in editing mode**, I'd like to have a `UISlider` that sets the value of the right UILabel, so that the result would look like this:

[image]

Could someone point me to the right direction? I'm not even sure if I should do that by subclassing `UITableViewCell` or in IB. Code snippets would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: can you post the code what you are doing in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I haven't done anything yet, but what do you have in mind regarding cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Very nice idea! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, create a new Navigation-based Project, then create a new class file named `CustomCell.h` and `CustomCell.m`, respectively.

Copy and paste this code into your **RootViewController.m** file:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation RootViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=self.editButtonItem;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.mainLabel.text=@"ValueName";

    return cell;
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView.editing){
        return 70;
    }
    return 44;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return NO;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

### CustomCell.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *mainLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *detailLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISlider *slider;

@end
```

### CustomCell.m:

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell
@synthesize mainLabel, detailLabel, slider;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 12, 280, 0)];
        slider.alpha = 0;
        slider.maximumValue = 30;
        slider.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
        [self.contentView addSubview:slider];
        [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
        [slider release];

        mainLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 12, 150, 20)];
        mainLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        mainLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];
        [mainLabel release];

        detailLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width-180, 12, 150, 20)];
        detailLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentRight;
        detailLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", lroundf(slider.value)];
        detailLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        detailLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:detailLabel];
        [detailLabel release];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    if(editing){
        slider.alpha = 1;
        slider.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    }else{
        slider.alpha = 0;
        slider.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(IBAction) sliderChanged:(id) sender{
    detailLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", lroundf(slider.value)];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Compile and run and you have a perfectly fine version of the controls you wanted. I even implemented animations as smooth as butter. Have fun!

EDIT:
If you do want to use the editing-controls, you must not implement the following method and have to adjust the frame of the labels and the slider.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer - it works very good! I just had to add -(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
} so if you want, edit your answer for future reference..

Answer (score 24):

Being a sucker for bounties, i sat down and experimented a bit. This is what i have found to be the cleanest solution :

You will make a custom cell class. As i read from your post, you have no problem with this, and I belive it really is the only way.

In the header file:

```
@interface TableCellSlider : UITableViewCell {
    UISlider *cellSlider;
}
```

In the main file :

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        cellSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 10, 100, 20)];
        [self addSubview:cellSlider];
        cellSlider.hidden = YES;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
{ 
    if (self.editing) {
        cellSlider.hidden = NO;
    } else {
        cellSlider.hidden = YES;
    }
}

- (float)getValue {
    return cellSlider.value;
}
```

As for the table and the cell height, add this to the table script :

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [super setEditing:editing animated:YES];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    //[self.tableView reloadData];
}


    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    { 
        if (self.editing) {
            return 50;
        } else {
            return 30;
        }
    }
```

This should do the trick. You can use the getValue on the cells, so you don't have to synthesize the sliders, and they will hide/reappear for whatever reason the cells become editable.

Best of luck with your project :]

Comment: Doesn't the `[self.tableView reloadData];` call interrupt the animation on the `setEditing` method?

Comment: You are absolutely right marza, i didn't think of that. I changed the code to use the Updates system instead, which luckily also reloads cell heights. :] Issue fixed

Comment: Even if the question is not mine, I like it and I like your solution too (now).

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for! Actually I got it working, but now I try to animate the UISlider so that it fades in/out together with the cell. I added a [UIView beginAnimations] block, but unfortunately it gets called after the transition of the cell finishes. Any idea about that??

Comment: Instead of hide/showing it in didTransitionToState , you can change its frame x to either its right place, or tableview.frame.width. This will slide it offscreen when its not supposed to be shown, no matter rotation or table size.

Comment: I would recommend to have the a class method on the cell's class that returns the height instead of hard-coding it in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndex:`. This way all the knowledge would be encapsulated in the cell class. You would then simply do something like `return [MyShinyCellClass preferredHeightWithEditingMode:self.editing];`

Comment: Also, to reload the cell animated, use the [reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:) inside the `beginUpdates/endUpdates` block.

Comment: @DarkDust : Yes, that would actually not be a bad idea. There would be nothing wrong in doing this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I finally accepted the one from Fscheidl, but this one is very good as well.

Answer (score 4):

you need to reconfigure your cell in the delgate method named

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

this method is called when ever user swaps the cell for deleting

where you can find the cell by the method of UITableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and then reconfigure it

for more information refer developer documentation

Answer (score 3):

As far as my knowledge is concerned you can add your slider when the editing begins. I mean in the following method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    /*  Add your slider.  */
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just blindly shooting, as I have not implemented it by my own, But, Reloading table with the new size may help, you can overwrite, following method while being in edit mode..

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
    return (int)yourHeight;
}
```

Comment: I also thought about that and I'll start by implementing somithing similar, but I hope (and feel) that there should be a better solution..

Comment: reloading the table will loose the delete button in red ... and by this method you will never be able to edit the cell because every time you try to delete the table reload it sets its table view sets its editing property to NO

Comment: @Irene: Yeah I too think same as as you, hope for the best :)